# Getting NumberFormatException in map reduce program for some strange reason

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Not sure why I'm getting this error.  I installed hadoop 2.7.3 via brew on my MBP.  I think I'm running it in single node

Everything I'm asking about is from [this hadoop tutorial site](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hadoop/hadoop_mapreduce.htm).  I'm getting a NumberFormatException error, but it says it's "null".

First, here's the input file:

```
1979 23 23 2 43 24 25 26 26 26 26 25 26 25
1980 26 27 28 28 28 30 31 31 31 30 30 30 29
1981 31 32 32 32 33 34 35 36 36 34 34 34 34
1984 39 38 39 39 39 41 42 43 40 39 38 38 40
1985 38 39 39 39 39 41 41 41 00 40 39 39 45
```

Only one space between each integer.  The only weird thing is the single digit number but that's not null.

Next, here's the error message I get when running the program:

```
snip snip
snip snip
17/03/06 17:21:40 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local1731001664_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null      // complains something is null here
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:454)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at com.servicenow.bigdata.ProcessUtil$E_EMapper.map(ProcessUtil.java:35)
    at com.servicenow.bigdata.ProcessUtil$E_EMapper.map(ProcessUtil.java:16)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

snip snip
snip snip
```

Lastly, here's a snippet from the offending line/function above:

```
  public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,  // offending line #16 here
  OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output,   
  Reporter reporter) throws IOException 
  { 
     String line = value.toString(); 
     String lasttoken = null; 
     StringTokenizer s = new StringTokenizer(line,"\t"); 
     String year = s.nextToken(); 

     while(s.hasMoreTokens())
        {
           lasttoken=s.nextToken();
        } 

     int avgprice = Integer.parseInt(lasttoken);  // offneding #35 line here
     output.collect(new Text(year), new IntWritable(avgprice));
```

Thanks in advance for your help.  Hopefully I'm not wasting people's time if this is a simple mistake.

Comment: seems `s.hasMoreTokens()` is `false` from the beginning on, therefore `lasttoken` remains `null` and hence the `NumberFormatException: null` when trying to parse it. Also, if there is a `space` between each number and you are trying to split the tokens with a `tab` there won't be any tokens.

Comment: @jlordo Thanks.  I had spaces instead of tabs b/c stupid me, when I cut an pasted, the tab turned into multiple spaces.  While debugging, I removed all spaces and didn't think to make it into a tab.  Still didn't work but thanks for pointing this out to me.

Comment: @jlordo, if you make your comment into an answer, i'll upvote it too since i was stupid and you pointed out my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `s.hasMoreTokens()` is false from the beginning on, therefore `lasttoken` remains `null` and hence the `NumberFormatException: null` when trying to parse it.
Also, if there is a space `' '` between each number and you are trying to split the tokens with a tab `'\t'`there won't be any tokens

Answer (score 1):

1. TutorialsPoint has outdated code. It tells you to download Hadoop 1.2.1? That is several years old... Go check the official Hadoop MapReduce tutorials.
2. You have no tabs in your data that you copied, just spaces.
3. You can test that same exact code outside of MapReduce.

You can replace all that string stuff with this

```
if (value == null) return null;
String[] splits = value.toString().split("\\s+"); 
String year = splits[0];
String lasttoken = splits[splits.length - 1];
```

Comment: thx, stupid me.  When I cut and pasted, the tab turned into several spaces.  I tried fiddling with the spaces and thus like you said, no tokens since there was no tab to break on.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that your text file has only Space delimiter.
2. Change the Code as following also works.

   `StringTokenizer s = new StringTokenizer(line,"\t");`